# Microsoft Logging with open generic types and Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, logging, dependency-injection

I'm really trying to wrap my head around all of this.

I want to use the ILogger in my "AddTextCalculator1" Example class using open generic types.

[As noted here](https://stackify.com/net-core-dependency-injection/)

First I register the Services

```
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddLogging()
    .BuildServiceProvider();

var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>()
    .CreateLogger<Program>();

var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddInternalServices();
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>)));
services.AddTextCalculator1();

var testCalculatorOneService = provider.GetService<ISomeCalculationOne>();
```

Then the IServiceCollectionExtension class

```
public static class IServiceCollectionExtension
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddTextCalculator1(this IServiceCollection services )
    {
        //services.AddTransient<ISomeCalculationOne>(s => new SomeCalculationOne(serviceProvider));
        services.AddTransient<ISomeCalculationOne, SomeCalculationOne>();
        return services;
    }
}
```

My Interface

```
public interface ISomeCalculationOne 
{
    void DoSomeCalcAndOutputToScreen();
}
```

And then my class

```
public class SomeCalculationOne : ISomeCalculationOne
{
    public ILogger _logger { get; private set; }

    public SomeCalculationOne(ILogger<SomeCalculationOne> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _logger.LogInformation("Constructed - HOT DAIMN!!!!");
    }

    public void DoSomeCalcAndOutputToScreen()
    {
        int a = 1 + 1;
        _logger.LogDebug("This is a debug logging test");
        Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
    }
}
```

It's currently throwing an error because I am not passing in logger of type ILogger into my constructor (Notice the commented out code in my  IServiceCollectionExtension class)

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory' while attempting to
>   activate 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger`

But that would mean I would have to pass in logger of type ILogger when defining my services

```
services.AddTextCalculator1(ILogger<SomeCalculationOne> bla);
```

But that just completely defies the point of adding logger to my services in the first place, or I'm I not understanding it correctly?

Comment: You've not registered the an instance of ILoggerFactory which is a required dependency of concrete impl Logger I would guess. The actual open generic registration looks good to me.

Comment: `SomeCalculationOne` CTOR will throw an NRE. `_logger` is never set to `logger`, but `a` is. When trying to call LogInformation on _logger, it will be null. Sidenote: Why is _logger public?

Comment: @Fildor Ah, That was me incorrectly copying it over to stackoverflow. Updated how I have it now. Thanks

Comment: @Mardoxx Why would I need ILoggerFactory though? What would be the purpose of the the factory in this case?

Comment: @Ruan  So a `Logger<T>` is a clever way of having specific loggers for different classes, effectively tagging them based on class. It has a method `Log` which internally redirects this to `Log` of an `ILogger` to do the actual logging. Therefore it requires an implementation of `ILoggerFactory` to provide the implementation of `ILogger`! Looking at the source code may help with the intuition https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/LoggerOfT.cs

Comment: @Mardoxx Looks like I just forgot to register
services.AddLogging();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like I just forgot to register

```
services.AddLogging();
```